# Querying Apache Solr with JSON values in brackets

Tags: java, apache, search, solr, full-text-search

When using Apache Solr's browser search tool (on localhost), when I query *:* (return all), the GET request returns results in the following format:

```
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":12,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1562080387377"}},
  "response":{"numFound":164,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "name":["Maria Atkinson"],
        "email":["krandolph@yahoo.com"],
        "phone_number":["(408)500-6026x750"],
        "password":["password"],
        "_version_":1637959617282572288},
```

where all the values are in square brackets.

This is a problem because I cannot GET results based on a query name, e.g. query
`select?q=Maria` returns nothing.

I did a POST request of the JSON file with the following command in Terminal:
`bin/post -c techproducts /Users/**/Desktop/**/upload.json`

My 2 questions are:

1. What causes this square brackets behaviour?
2. How can I query values which are enclosed in square brackets?

**NOTE**

In my JSON file upload, the values are not enclosed in square brackets, in the following format:

`[{"id": 1, "name": "Maria Atkinson", "email": "krandolph@yahoo.com", "phone_number": "(408)500-6026x750", "password": "password"}, ...`

Comment: The `[` and `]` is just the JSON format for an array (i.e. the field is multi-valued). They're not relevant to how a hit is determined. First guess is that you're missing the field name: `q=name:Maria` and the default search field hasn't got the content. If you haven't created an explicit schema, that should give you a hit. However, if you _have_ created an explicit schema and set the type to string, only exact matches will give hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your schema.xml. The fields must be having multivalued as true. Change the same to false.
Once you change the `multiValued=false` in the schema.xml for all your fields.
Re index the data again.

MultiValued defined in the schema whether the field is allowed to have more than one value. For instance: if I have a fieldType called ID which is `multiValued=true` indexing a document such as this: `doc { id : [ 1, 2] ... }`.

Mark the fields to `multiValued=false`. Re index the data.

Your search problem will get solved.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answers from Abhijit and MatsLindh, the default field for Solr is text, as defined in the [Solr docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html). As I didn't define a field, it defaulted to text.

However, there is no field called text in my indexed documents, so nothing was returned.